# MATLAB Matrix Problem

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a system of equations (5 in total) with 5 unknowns. I've set these out into matrices to try solve, but I'm not sure if this comes out right. Basically the setup is `AX = B`, where `A`,`X`, and `B` are matrices. `A` is a 5x5, `X` is a 1x5 and `B` is a 5x1.

When I use MATLAB to solve for `X` using the formula `X = A\B`, it gives me a warning:

```
Matrix is singular to working precision.
```

and gives me 0 for all 5 X unknowns, but if I say `X = B\A` it doesnt, and gives me values for the 5 `X` unknowns.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? In case this is important, this is what my `X` matrix looks like:

```
X= [1/C3; 1/P1; 1/P2; 1/P3; 1/P4]
```

Where `C3`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4` are my unknowns.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is *singular*, which means its determinant is 0. Such system of equations does not give you enough information to find a unique solution. One odd thing I see in your question is that **X** is 1x5 while **B** is 5x1. This is *not* a correct way of posing the problem. Both **X** and **B** must be 5x1. In case you're wondering, this is *not* a Matlab thing - this is a linear algebra thing. This `[5x5]*[1x5]` is illegal. This `[5x5]*[5x1]` produces a `[5x1]` result. This `[1x5]*[5x5]` produces a `[1x5]` result. Check you algebra first, and then check whether the determinant (`det` function in Matlab) is 0.

Comment: Knew it was going to be my error ;) checked it, and my matrix A is a 5x5, matrix B is a 5x1 and matrix X is a 5x1 as well. Does that make more sense? My linear algebra is a little shakey at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to be. Have you checked whether you matrix's determinant is 0?

Comment: Yeah, the det is 0 for matrix A. So that's where the problem lies? I must have made a mistake in making the matrices from my equations.

Comment: Not necessarily. That only means that your vectors are not linearly independent. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrV1xCWdY-g), I believe, delivers a good explanation for the concept of linear independence.

Comment: Ok I see. It doesn't, however, explain why my values in X are zeroes, as this shouldn't be the case

Comment: When Matlab cannot give you a solution, it sets your answer to all zeros. That's just a Matlab thing.

Comment: If you post the code, I can check over it. and see what result my Matlab will produce. They may differ from distribution to distribution.

Answer (score 0):

So, the next thing is to figure out why `A` is singular.  (Note that it's possible that you'd want to solve

`A x = b`

in cases with square and singular `A`, but they'd only be in cases where `b` is in the range space of `A`.)

Maybe you can write your matrix `A` and vector `b` out (since it's only 5x5)?  Or explain how you create it.  That might give a clue as to why `A` isn't full rank or as to why `b` isn't in the range space of `A`.